# Extract Title from html link

Tags: regex, vb.net

I have the following HTML string:

```
<a href="/tothepage" title="the page">The Link</a>.
```

How can I extract title from the HTML snippet with ease? Either a regex or other VB.NET solution is preferred but C# is ok.

I want 'the page' not the link text: I want the value of the title attribute.

I have HTMLAgilityPack installed if it's easy to do it with that.

Comment: Are u trying to get the portion between the quotes `the page` or the string between the tags  `The Link` ?

Comment: I want 'the page' not 'the link', I want the attribute title.  I have HTMLAgilityPack installed if its easy to do with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a regular expression, the group will contain it `([^"]*)`:

```
title="([^"]*)"
```

C#

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string originalString = "<a href=\" / tothepage\" title=\"the page\">The Link</a>.";
        Regex rgx = new Regex("title=\"([^\"]*)\"", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        Match match = rgx.Matches(originalString)[0];
        Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1]);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: Could you put it into a .NET line please.

Comment: The `+` should be a `*`, because the title could be explicitly given, but still empty.

Comment: Thx for the code, know of but hardly used Regular Expressions.

Answer (score 2):

As you have the HtmlAgilityPack already, you can extract the "title" attribute like this:

```
Option Infer On
Option Strict On

Imports HtmlAgilityPack

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim a = "<a href=""/tothepage"" title=""the page"">The Link</a>."
        Dim doc As New HtmlDocument()
        doc.LoadHtml(a)
        Dim node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("/a")
        Dim title = node?.Attributes("title")?.Value

        Console.WriteLine(title) ' outputs "the page"

        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

End Module
```

Of course, you won't need that many lines of code as that is a complete working example.

The `?.` parts prevent it from throwing an error if `node` is Nothing (in this case if there wasn't an "<a>" element) and prevent it from throwing an error if there is no "title" attribute.

Comment: It never transpired to me that I needed to treat the hyperlink string as a document.  Thx, I got what I needed.

Comment: @MiscellaneousUser While you *can* parse small amounts of some HTML with regexes, it is usually not a good idea - reasons for that are given in the quite amusing post [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1115360).